# Confused with this.props.children with react-router v1.0.0

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have router like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
  <Route path="info" component={Info}>
    <Route path="c/:cid" component={CompanyDetail} />
    <Route path="p/:pid" component={ProjectDetail} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

My Info component is a High Order Component connected by `react-redux`.

As change in react-router v1.0.0, `this.props.children` in Info component should represent CompanyDetail component if `/info/c/123` is reached. But I got this when I try to reach `/info`:

[image]

I seem the value of `this.props.children` in Info component is itself? And if I try to reach `/info/c/123`, also got this issue, Info component contains Info component itself which contains CompanyDetail component.

[image]

It's confusing to me, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define CompanyDetail and ProjectDetail routes as child route of Info route.

eg:

```
<Route path="info" component={Info}>
    <Route path="info/c/:cid" component={CompanyDetail} />
    <Route path="info/p/:pid" component={ProjectDetail} />
</Route>
```

Comment: Sorry for my typo, I do define routes like this, and i fixed it above. And I add a screenshot of react dev tool.

Comment: Have you tried `path="info/c/:cid"` like this, Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. I find the old code in my App component which contain code:

```
React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.props})
```

Fixed by preventing copy `this.props.children` to children.